# Search on Google with Python and grab the "do you mean" information for typo correction

Tags: python

I'm working on an OCR project. In the postprocessing phase, I want to use Google's "do you mean" function to auto-correct errors. How can I implement this with Python?
I saw this https://simplestepscode.com/autocomplete-data-tutorial/, but it is in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use autocorrect
Example Usage:

```
from autocorrect import Speller

spell = Speller(lang='en')

x=input('enter a word')
word=spell(x)
if word == x :
   print (x)
else :
   print('did you mean '+word)
```

let x be survice

Result:

```
  did you mean service
```

let x be service

Result:

```
 service
```

Comment: Great. Does this module need internet access?

Comment: Thanks! It works. However, it's not accurate enough according to my test (maybe because the corpus is not large enough). That's why I need google searching results to get an accurate result.

Comment: oh cool you can try using nltk for that but iam not sure how to use it